# Why after updating pods do I keep getting Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I know this is because the StorageMetadata is not being used anymore. I saw other generic answers to similar questions point to this firebase documentation.: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files I tried to apply it to my code, but it doesn't work. How should I apply it to my current function?

```
{




        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("PhotoPosts")
        let newPostRef1 = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("PhotoPosts1")


        let newPostKey = newPostRef.key



        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.001){

            let imageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(uid)


            let newImageRef = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef.key!)
            let newImageRef1 = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef1.key!)


            newImageRef.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
                self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                newPostRef.setValue(self.imageDownloadURL as Any)


            })



            newImageRef1.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
                self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                let keyToPost = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).childByAutoId().key
                let f1: [String: Any] = [(keyToPost) : self.imageDownloadURL as Any]

                newPostRef1.updateChildValues(f1)




                               })


            let caption = ServerValue.timestamp() as! [String : Any]
            Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("caption").setValue(caption)


        }

    }
```

Like I mentioned, I tried to apply the firebase documentation to my function as shown below. It still gives basically the same error. Where am I going wrong?

```
 func save() {




        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("PhotoPosts")
        let newPostRef1 = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("PhotoPosts1")


        let newPostKey = newPostRef.key



        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.001){

            let imageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(uid)


            let newImageRef = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef.key!)
            let newImageRef1 = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef1.key!)
            newImageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
              if let error = error {



              } else {

                newImageRef.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
                                  self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                                  newPostRef.setValue(self.imageDownloadURL as Any)


                              })
                // Here you can get the download URL for 'simpleImage.jpg'
              }
            }
```

....

UPDATE after first answer: This is what I tried for the double database entry part:

```
     newImageRef1.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
                                      newImageRef1.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                                        guard let downloadURL = url else {
                                          return
                                        }
                                        let keyToPost = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).childByAutoId().key
                                        let f1: [String: Any] = [(keyToPost) : self.imageDownloadURL as Any]

                                        newPostRef1.updateChildValues(f1)
                                      }
                                    })
```

I get following error at let f1: `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected dictionary key type 'String'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting:

> Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'

If you look at the [documentation for `StorageMetadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata) you'll see that it indeed doesn't have a `downloadURL` member. This member was dropped in the SDK updates of May 2018, so is long gone.

The correct way to get the download URL is shown in the documentation on [uploading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory):

> ```
> // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
> let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
>   guard let metadata = metadata else {
>     // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
>     return
>   }
>   // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
>   let size = metadata.size
>   // You can also access to download URL after upload.
>   riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
>     guard let downloadURL = url else {
>       // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
>       return
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

In your case, that'd be something like:

```
newImageRef.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
  newImageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    guard let downloadURL = url else {
      return
    }
    newPostRef.setValue(url)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. Do you have any alternative idea? I get a non terminal error Value 'downloadURL' was defined but never used; consider replacing with boolean test. But I get a terminal error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type NSURL at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray

Comment: I have fix that by defining downloadURL as a String? but then I'd get this at f1: reason: '(updateChildValues:) Cannot store object of type __SwiftValue at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

Comment: I put a new question here. I'll mark both once solution found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594804/cannot-store-nsurl-and-swiftvalue-can-only-store-objects-of-type-nsnumber-ns

Comment: I'll mark it as correct even though it still produces error Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary. I am still trying to figure out how to fix that.